# Docker Hub - Automated Build failed, but local build without problems

Tags: dockerhub

I have created the repository `ldaume/docker-highcharts-server` in the Docker Hub Registry which is connected to a github repository which contains the Dockerfile.

If I build the image locally it works like a charm.

But the automated build fails with the error `Unknown Build Error.` and no logs. The only content I can see in the build informations is the `Dockerfile`, so docker had no problems with github ;).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my scenario I had a file in my current directory that was not checked in, but in my Dockerfile I had it `COPY`ing it into the container. Have you looked into that possibility?